# How can this character be dead?

Tags: doctor-who

By the end of *Death in Heaven (S8 E12)*, it seems that

> Danny Pink is dead

How can this be, when

> Clara and Danny had a descendent

in a previous episode in this series?

Comment: Because wibbly wobbly timey wimey.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It may be that the descendant that we saw

> (Orson Pink in *Listen*)

isn’t actually a descendant of

> Clara and Danny.

Although there are certainly circumstantial details in *Listen* that point strongly to that conclusion, *Listen*’s big theme is circumstantial details that point strongly to a conclusion (i.e. there being a race with perfectly evolved hiding capabilities that cannot be perceived), which in fact is not true. The idea of that character being a “descendant” may be similarly untrue.

Alternatively, the last state in which we see

> Danny, i.e. trapped in a disintegrating Nethersphere

may not be that character’s final fate. This is Doctor Who. People come back.

And one last possibility — in the cafe, before

> Clara says goodbye to the Doctor,

she said that she had something to tell him. We can’t really be sure what that was. Maybe...

> ...she’s *pregnant*?

Although we never see any evidence of that in the rest of Clara’s run on the series, so probably not.

Comment: I think the last point is probably the correct one. Remember the phone conversation at the start of the previous part? It seems likely that that was going to be one of the reasons for the call.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: maybe. Kinda takes the romance out of it if so — “I’m never going to tell anyone else that I love them... mainly because you’ve knocked me up.”

Comment: It could also be that that timeline has now simply been overwritten, like what they talked about in "In the Forest of the Night" - if a solar flare wipes out Earth in the modern day, then episodes set in Earth's/humanity's future can no longer happen. By the time of "Listen", Danny hadn't yet been converted, so his future was still in flux, and it was possible that Orson could come from that future, until "Death in Heaven" established differently.

Comment: @Amy That’s a very good point.

Comment: with the last comments i assumed it was because of the kid Danny brought back to life (the one he killed as a solider) and she was going to tell him she has to help this kid (raise him if she can't find his parents) and can no longer travel with him but because she was wearing The Master's bracelet the doctor assumed Danny was back. Because she's doesn't know The Doctor's first rule she didn't want to spoil the mood of him having found Gallifrey

Comment: @Memor-X: yeah, that makes sense too — more than the pregnancy theory.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I'd certainly go with the adoption theroy - at least that was my first impression on the first viewing.

Comment: I am firmly in the "preggers" camp. I think Clara phoning Danny right before his accident was to break the happy news.  Calling to say "I love you" is fine, but I think she wanted to let him know she meant it that time because of the bun in the oven.

Comment: @Chahk — I think at this point we can be fairly certain Clara wasn’t pregnant. At least as certain as Doctor who allows.